# Can port forwarding reveal destination IP?

Tags: security, iptables, port-forwarding, firewalld, privacy

I am forwarding incoming TCP connections to a different host in the local network using firewalld / iptables.

Is there a scenario where the remote connections are able to determine the IP of the destination from the responses?

I am not talking about application level (webservers that leak that info in their HTTP response for example). But just on a TCP level, so packet headers, traceroutes, network errors, etc.

Comment: Forwarded packets don’t reveal anything. For the responses they generate though… Your mileage may vary depending on the protocol and application concerned.

Comment: @Rob I don't mean on a protocol/application level, but purely the TCP headers from the reponses. But since almost every home router in the world can do port forwarding, and I never heard stories this leaks local LAN IP's, I guess the answer to my question is that it is not technically possible.